# 'ServerRequestForm' object has no attribute 'get' on form post Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to submit a form in django consisting of 3 models and a 3 way dependable dropdown. Every form validations and other function of dropdowns and dynamically adding teacher fields works but while submission it shows: `'ServerRequestForm' object has no attribute 'get'`
I have provided with views, models and forms for the problem.
`views.py`

```
class ServerRequestView(FormView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/school/request_Server_bak.html'
    form_class = ServerRequestForm
    mediator_form_class = MediatorForm
    teacher_form_class = TeacherForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('server_request_success')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['mediator_form'] = self.mediator_form_class()
        context['teacher_formset'] = TeacherFormSet()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()

        # Check if self.request.POST is a QueryDict object
        if isinstance(request.POST, QueryDict):
            mediator_form = self.mediator_form_class(request.POST)
            teacher_formset = TeacherFormSet(request.POST)
        else:
            # handle the case where request.POST is not a QueryDict object
            # e.g. by raising an error or using a default value
            raise ValueError("request.POST is not a QueryDict object")

        if form.is_valid() and mediator_form.is_valid() and teacher_formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, mediator_form, teacher_formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, mediator_form, teacher_formset)

    def form_valid(self, form, mediator_form, teacher_formset):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.mediator = mediator_form.save()
        self.object.save()

        teacher_instances = teacher_formset.save(commit=False)
        for teacher in teacher_instances:
            teacher.server_request = self.object
            teacher.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form, mediator_form, teacher_formset):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form, mediator_form=mediator_form, teacher_formset=teacher_formset)
        )
```

`forms.py`

```
class ServerRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Server request form for schools
    This uses a three way chained dependent dropdown for province, district and city
    """
    
    class Meta:
        model = SchoolProfile
        fields = ('school_name','school_type', 'phone','no_of_teachers',
        'no_of_students','no_of_laptops','no_of_desktops',
        'internet_availability', 'province', 'district', 
        'city', 'head_teacher_name','head_contact')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['district'].queryset = District.objects.none()
    
        if 'province' in self.data:
            try:
                province_id = int(self.data.get('province'))
                self.fields['district'].queryset = District.objects.filter(province_id=province_id).order_by('name')
            except(ValueError,TypeError):
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty District queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['district'].queryset = self.instance.province.district_set.order_by('name')

        self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.none()
        if 'district' in self.data:
            try:
                district_id = int(self.get('district'))
                self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.filter(district_id=district_id).order_by('name')

            except(ValueError,TypeError):
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset

        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['city'].queryset = self.instance.district.city_set.order_by('name')

class MediatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for mediator if any on server request
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Mediator
        fields = ('name', 'contact')

class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        label = 'teacher name',
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter Teacher name',
        })
    )
    contact = forms.CharField(
        label = 'teacher contact',
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter teacher contact info',
        })
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['name','contact']
TeacherFormSet = formset_factory(TeacherForm, extra=1)
```

I have the following fields on my `models.py`

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class District(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    district  = models.ForeignKey(
        District, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Mediator(models.Model):
    name =   models.CharField(
        _("Mediator's Name"),
        max_length = 80,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    contact = models.CharField(
        _("Mediator's Number"),
        max_length = 10,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )

class HeadTeacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Head Teacher's Name"),
        max_length=80,
    )
    contact = models.CharField(
        _("Head Teacher's Phone Number"),
        max_length=10,
    )

class SchoolProfile(models.Model):
    """
    School model
    """
    # TODO: Add school type selection in dropdown
    SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        ("basic", _("Basic")),
        ("primary", _("Primary")),
    )
    INTERNET_CHOICES = (
        ("yes", _("Available")),
        ("no", _("Unavailable"))
    )
    MEDIATOR_CHOICES = (
        ("yes",_("Yes")),
        ("no", _("No"))
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="school")
    school_name = models.CharField(
        _("School name"),
        max_length=255,
    )
    school_type = models.CharField(
        _("School Type"),
        max_length = 220,
        choices = SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default = 'basic'
    )
    emis = models.CharField(
        _("School EMIS Number"),
        unique=True,
        max_length=10
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        _("School Contact Number"),
        max_length=10,
        null = True
    )
    no_of_teachers = models.IntegerField(
        _("Number of Teachers"),
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    no_of_students = models.IntegerField(
        _("Number of Students"),
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    no_of_laptops = models.IntegerField(
        _("Number of Laptops"),
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    no_of_desktops = models.IntegerField(
        _("Number of Desktops"),
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    internet_availability = models.CharField(
        _("Internet Availability"),
        max_length = 5,
        choices = INTERNET_CHOICES,
        default = "no",
    )
    province = models.ForeignKey(
        Province, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null = True
    )
    district = models.ForeignKey(
        District, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null = True
    )
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True
    )
    # teacher = models.ForeignKey(
    #     Teacher, 
    #     on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
    #     null = True
    # )
    mediator_bool = models.CharField(
        _("Are you a mediator filling this form on the behalf of School?"),
        choices = MEDIATOR_CHOICES,
        max_length = 3,
        default = "no"
    )
    mediator = models.ForeignKey(
        Mediator, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null =True
    )
    head_teacher_name = models.CharField(
        _("Head Teacher's Name"),
        max_length=80,
        null=True
    )
    head_contact = models.CharField(
        _("Head Teacher's Phone Number"),
        max_length=10,
        null=True
    )
  
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Teacher's name"),
        max_length = 80,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    contact = models.CharField(
        _("Teacher's Number"),
        max_length = 10,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    school = models.ForeignKey(
        SchoolProfile, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="teachers",
        default=1
    )

class ServerRequest(models.Model):
    """
    Model for school's server requests
    """
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("pending", _("Pending")),
        ("approved", _("Approved")),
        ("in process", _("In Process")),
        ("fulfilled ", _("Fullfilled")),
        ("rejected", _("Rejected")),
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        _("Status"),
        max_length=40,
        choices = STATUS_CHOICES,
        default = "pending"
    )
    server_model = models.CharField(
        _("Server Model"),
        max_length = 20,
        null = True, 
        blank = True,
    )
    remarks = models.TextField(
        _("Remarks"),
        max_length = 225,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
    )
    school = models.ForeignKey(
        SchoolProfile, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

`template.html`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <form action="." method="post" id="server-request-form" 
            data-districts-url="{% url 'dashboard:ajax_load_districts' %}"
            data-cities-url="{% url 'dashboard:ajax_load_cities' %}"
            >
                {% csrf_token %} {{ server_form | crispy }}  
                {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for teacher in teacher_formset %}
                <div class="row form-row spacer">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label>{{ teacher.name.label }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            {{ teacher.name }} {{ teacher.contact }}
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <label for="has_mediator">Are you a mediator filling this form on the behalf of School?</label>
                <select id="has_mediator" name="has_mediator">
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no" selected>No</option>
                </select>

              <div class="mediator_fields" id="field1">
                {{ mediator_form | crispy }}
              </div>
               {% include "license_agreement.html" %}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn ole-btn">
            </form><br>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock dashboard_content %}
```

Trying to submit the form to the designated models and create a relationship to the model serverRequest upon submission.
The error seems to be on the get method of the forms to retrive district based on province provided. I've used the code from [here](https://github.com/masbhanoman/django_3way_chained_dropdown_list) for the chained dropdown feature.
But it shows the following error:

```
 in view   
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\olen\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\olen\olen-elib\src\pustakalaya_apps\dashboard\school_views.py", line 103, in post
    form = self.get_form()
  File "C:\olen\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 45, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
_    district_id = int(self.get('district'))
AttributeError: 'ServerRequestForm' object has no attribute 'get'
[basehttp].ERROR "POST /en/dashboard/server/request/ HTTP/1.1" 500 105950
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here in the `ServerRequestForm` class:

```
    if 'district' in self.data:
        try:
            district_id = int(self.get('district'))
                              ^^^^^^
```

It should be:

```
    if 'district' in self.data:
        try:
            district_id = int(self.data.get('district'))
```